# Bolding/italicizing parenthesized text

Tags: bug

When I use asterisks to bold/italicize by `**（**` inside (right after) zenkaku text, I get the following - （, 【, { are not bolded:

**INPUT**

```
あ**（**  あ<b>（</b>

い*a*  い<i>a</i>

う**＜**  う<b>＜</b>

え**【**  え<b>【</b>

お*{*  お<i>{</i>
```

**OUTPUT**

あ**（**  あ**（**

い*a*  い*a*

う**＜**  う**＜**

え**【**  え**【**

お*{*  お*{*

Is this a known bug or a designed behavior?

Comment: どう見えています？私には(PCから)、２つ目の a と、３つ目の ＜ が、ちゃんと斜めと太字になって見えてますが、１つ目、４つ目、５つ目はダメですね。アスタリスクでダメな時は、`<b> </b>` で挟んだらうまくいくかもしれませんが、どうでしょう？

Comment: @Chocolate すいません、2，3番目はただのサンプルでした。見え方としては同じです。